# How do I find the index of variable b from list a?

Tags: python, indexing

How do I find the index of variable b from list a?
I suspect that the problem is in the data types.

```
a=[-202516736, '-202516736', '13886', '678280946', '14514', '330251838', '14511', '639566631', '14510', '542472303', '14506']
b=['678280946']
a_INT = [int(item) for item in a]
b_INT = [int(item) for item in b]

j = 0
while True:
    try:
        i = a_INT.index(b_INT, j)
        print(i)
        j = i + 1
    except:
        break
```

Comment: I think there are some conceptual issues here. Are you saying that you want to find **all** indexes in *a* where the single value in *b* (which, for some reason, is a list) exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take this a step further and add another value to the *b* list and also add a duplicate in the *a* list. Then:

```
a=[-202516736, '-202516736', '13886', '678280946', '14514', '678280946', '330251838', '14511', '639566631', '14510', '542472303', '14506']
b=['678280946', 13886]

ai = list(map(int, a))

for n in map(int, b):
    offset = 0
    r = []
    while True:
        try:
            i = ai[offset:].index(n)
            r.append(offset+i)
            offset += i + 1
        except ValueError:
            break
    print(f'{n} occurs at {r}')
```

**Output:**

```
678280946 occurs at [3, 5]
13886 occurs at [2]
```

**Version 2:**

The first piece of code is functionally correct. However, it could be very inefficient if the list being searched is very large.

Python's built-in sort function is very fast. So, let's build a list of 2-tuples each made up of a value from the list and its original index. Then sort the new list. Now that it's sorted we can perform a binary search and move on from there.

Added some more values to the OP's original list for demonstration purposes:

```
a = [-202516736, '-202516736', '13886', '678280946', '14514', '678280946',
     '330251838', '14511', '639566631', '14510', '542472303', '14506', '678280946']
b = ['678280946', 13886, 14514, '-202516736', 99]


def bsearch(lst, x):
    L = 0
    R = len(lst) - 1
    while L <= R:
        m = (L + R) // 2
        if (v := lst[m][0]) == x:
            return m
        if v < x:
            L = m + 1
        else:
            R = m - 1
    return -1


def findall(list_, n):
    templist = sorted((v, i) for i, v in enumerate(list_))
    result = None
    if (i := bsearch(templist, n)) >= 0:
        result = [templist[i][1]]
        for j in range(i-1, -1, -1):
            if templist[j][0] != n:
                break
            result.append(templist[j][1])
        for j in range(i+1, len(templist)):
            if templist[j][0] != n:
                break
            result.append(templist[j][1])
    return result

ai = list(map(int, a))

for n in map(int, b):
    print(f'{n} -> {findall(ai, n)}')
```

**Output:**

```
678280946 -> [5, 3, 12]
13886 -> [2]
14514 -> [4]
-202516736 -> [0, 1]
99 -> None
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great solution, in fact I use this code to find the neighboring index element in the a list. 
If I search for '678280946' I need to return the index of the value '14514'. I think I can do it with your code. thanks.

Comment: @andrew199696 Don't forget to check to see if the given location is the last item in the list!

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[-202516736, '-202516736', '13886', '678280946', '14514', '330251838', '14511', '639566631', '14510', '542472303', '14506']
b=['678280946']
for item in b:
  print(a.index(item))
```

Since b has only one element the output is 3.

Comment: The fact is that the variable b can have several elements, I need to find out all the indexes

Comment: this doesn't find the elements, they have to be converted to int first.

Comment: Yes, I tried to do it with variables a_INT; b_INT; but it didn't help